# Date conversion in value read from excel in java

Tags: java, jsp

Mates,

I have a Date object which get populated with a value after reading from a excel

```
Date mydate = cell.getDateCellValue();
```

value loaded is  ***"Sat Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2016"**

I dont know why this format value is given out from excel though its displayed on different  format in excel.

I want to convert this DATE into `dd-mm-yyyy` format. How can this be done?

Tried this

```
String ms= "Sat Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2016"   ;  
          SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yy");      
          Date result = formater.parse(ms);
          System.out.println(result);
```

but gives output same as input.

Comment: `Tue Sep 19 13:52:47 CEST 2017` is the ouput for `System.out.println(new Date());` therefore you can only format the output but not how the date was saved

Comment: You're trying to parse the string "Sat Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2016", using the pattern "mm-dd-yy". How could that possibly work? Why are you trying to parse a String to a Date, since getDateCellValue() already returns a Date object, that you simply need to format the way you want to? parsing = String to Date. Formatting = Date to String.

Comment: Also `mm-dd-yy` is `minutes-day-year`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own Date class and override toString method with which ever format you want it to return #ApachePOI

```
public class CustomDate extends Date
{

public CustomDate(String string) 
{
    super(string);
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String format = formatter.format(this);

    return format;
}
}
```

And the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Date date = new Date("Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2012");
    String dateString  = date.toString();

    CustomDate customDate = new CustomDate(dateString);

    System.out.println(dateString);
    System.out.println(customDate.toString());
}
```

Use whatever format you want inside your toString method

Answer (score 0):

Do not conflate a date-time object with text that represents its value. **A `java.util.Date` has no “format”.** You are seeing text generated by that object’s `toString` method. That text does not exist inside the object. That class’ `toString` lies, applying the JVM’s current default  time zone to the  UTC value actually stored inside. One of many reasons to avoid this class altogether.

That `Date` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Convert your `java.util.Date` object to an `Instant`.

In Java 8 and later, look for new conversion methods added to the old classes. For Java 6 & Java 7, you'll be using the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. There you'll find a `DateTimeUtil` class offering conversion methods.

From our `Instant`, we can get a date. But first we must apply a time zone to move that `Instant` from UTC to the zone by which you want to perceive the date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate a string using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd -MM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Basil